# Encountered Exception in Data Driven with groovy

Tags: excel, groovy, automation, soapui

Not able to place the values from excel sheet into request.
With the following code, I am able to read the values from the excel sheet but not able to place it in the request.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.*;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.*;

log.info("Testing Started")
def reqOperationName = "getInsuranceDetails_1_FTC_005";
def inputDataFileName = "D:/SOAP UI Pro/MPI.xls"
def inputDataSheetName = "MPI"

Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName));
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName),workbook);
WritableSheet sheet1 = copy.getSheet(inputDataSheetName);

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def reqholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(reqOperationName+"#Request")
try{
    rowcount = sheet1.getRows();
    colcount = sheet1.getColumns();
    for(Row in 1..rowcount-1){
        for(Col in 2..colcount-1){
            String reqTagName = sheet1.getCell(Col,0).getContents()
            def TagCount = reqholder["count(//*:"+reqTagName+")"]
            if(TagCount!=0){
                String reqTagValue = sheet1.getCell(Col,Row).getContents()
                reqholder.setNodeValue("//*:"+reqTagName, reqTagValue)
                reqholder.updateProperty()                              
            }
        }
        //test the request
        testRunner.runTestStepByName(reqOperationName)
    //Read Response xml

def resholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(reqOperationName+"#Response")
resTagValue1= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:productID")
resTagValue2= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:accountNumber")
resTagValue3= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:insuranceCategory")
resTagValue4= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:imei")
resTagValue5= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:handsetMake")
resTagValue6= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:handsetModel")
resTagValue7= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:insurancePolicyName")
resTagValue8= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:insuranceStartTimestamp")        
//Write Response into excel sheet

Label resValue1= new Label(4,Row,resTagValue1);
sheet1.addCell(resValue1);   
Label resValue2= new Label(5,Row,resTagValue1);
sheet1.addCell(resValue1);
Label resValue3= new Label(6,Row,resTagValue1);
sheet1.addCell(resValue1);
Label resValue4= new Label(7,Row,resTagValue1);
sheet1.addCell(resValue1);
Label resValue5= new Label(8,Row,resTagValue1);
sheet1.addCell(resValue1);
Label resValue6= new Label(9,Row,resTagValue1);
sheet1.addCell(resValue1);
Label resValue7= new Label(10,Row,resTagValue1);
sheet1.addCell(resValue1);
Label resValue8= new Label(11,Row,resTagValue1);
sheet1.addCell(resValue1);

    }

}catch (Exception e) {log.info(e)}
finally{
    copy.write();
    copy.close();
    workbook.close();
}
log.info("Testing Over")
```

Following is the exception which i am getting in the console:

**INFO:java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath syntax error at char 11 on line 2 in {\ncount(//*:)}: expected "", found ")"**

Any help would really be appreciated.
Thanks,

Screenshot for the excel sheet and Request

Below are the attached screenshots for excel sheet and request

[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLFIZ.png)

Thank you,

Below are the codes which i am implementing in the groovy script.....

[Code part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Ib9.png)

[code part-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8MXU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the code which is mentioned below.... It has worked for me and now may be it will be helpful for you as well....

```
    import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
    import java.io.File
    import java.io.IOException
    import jxl.*
    import jxl.read.biff.BiffException
    import jxl.write.*
    import jxl.write.Label
    log.info("Testing Started")
    def reqOperationName = "getInsuranceDetails_1_FTC_005"
    def inputDataFileName = "D:/SOAP UI Pro/MPI.xls"
    def inputDataSheetName = "MPI"
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName))
    Sheet  sheet1 = workbook.getSheet(inputDataSheetName)


    def myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
    String xmlResponse = reqOperationName+"#Request"
    def reqholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(xmlResponse)
    try{
        rowcount = sheet1.getRows()
        colcount = sheet1.getColumns()

        for(Row in 1..rowcount-1){

        String reqTagName = sheet1.getCell(0,0).getContents()

        def TagCount = reqholder["count(//*:"+reqTagName+")"]

        if(TagCount!=0){
            String reqTagValue = sheet1.getCell(0,Row).getContents()
            if(reqTagValue!=null && !reqTagValue.isEmpty() && reqTagValue!="")
                    {
                        reqholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(xmlResponse)
                        log.info "extracted value : " + reqTagValue
                    reqholder.setNodeValue("//*:"+reqTagName, reqTagValue)
                    reqholder.updateProperty()        
                    log.info "node value : " + reqholder.getNodeValue("//*:"+reqTagName)
                    //test the request
                    testRunner.runTestStepByName(reqOperationName)
                    reqholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(reqOperationName+"#Response")
                    myList.add(reqholder.getPrettyXml().toString())
                    log.info myList[Row-1]
                    }                      
        }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {log.info(e)}
    finally{
        workbook.close()
    }
    Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName));
    WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName), existingWorkbook);

    try
    {
        WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet(inputDataSheetName);
        WritableCell cell;
        for (int i =1;i<myList.size();i++)
        {
        def resholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(myList[i])

        resTagValue1= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:productID")
        Label l = new Label(2, i+1, resTagValue1.toString());
        cell = (WritableCell) l;
        sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);

        resTagValue2= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:accountNumber")
        Label m = new Label(3, i+1, resTagValue2.toString());
        cell = (WritableCell) m;
        sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);

        resTagValue3= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:insuranceCategory")
        Label n = new Label(4, i+1, resTagValue3.toString());
        cell = (WritableCell) n;
        sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);

        resTagValue4= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:imei")
        Label o = new Label(5, i+1, resTagValue4.toString());
        cell = (WritableCell) o;
        sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);

        resTagValue5= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:handsetMake")
        Label p = new Label(6, i+1, resTagValue5.toString());
        cell = (WritableCell) p;
        sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);

        resTagValue6= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:handsetModel")
        Label q = new Label(7, i+1, resTagValue6.toString());
        cell = (WritableCell) q;
        sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);

        resTagValue7= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:insurancePolicyName")
    Label r = new Label(8, i+1, resTagValue7.toString());
    cell = (WritableCell) r;
    sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);

    resTagValue8= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:insuranceStartTimestamp")
    Label s = new Label(9, i+1, resTagValue8.toString());
    cell = (WritableCell) s;
    sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);

    resTagValue9= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:insuranceEndTimestamp")
    Label t = new Label(10, i+1, resTagValue9.toString());
    cell = (WritableCell) t;
    sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);
    }
  }
catch (Exception e) {log.info(e)}
finally{
     workbookCopy.write();
 workbookCopy.close();
 existingWorkbook.close();
}
log.info("Testing Over")
```

Let me know if has worked for you or has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the problem. The reason you are getting that error is because you are getting a null value from the excel sheet for that specific row and column combination(which means that there is no data in that cell). You don't need column loop as you have a single column.

Try this code below :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import jxl.*
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException
import jxl.write.*

log.info("Testing Started")
def reqOperationName = "getInsuranceDetails_1_FTC_005"
def inputDataFileName = "D:/SOAP UI Pro/MPI.xls"
def inputDataSheetName = "MPI"
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName))
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName),workbook)
WritableSheet sheet1 = copy.getSheet(inputDataSheetName)

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def reqholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(reqOperationName+"#Request")
try{
    rowcount = sheet1.getRows()
    colcount = sheet1.getColumns()

    for(Row in 1..rowcount-1){
    def cell = sheet1.getCell(0,0)
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
    String reqTagName = cell.getContents()
        log.info reqTagName
        def TagCount = reqholder["count(//*:"+reqTagName+")"]
        if(TagCount!=0){
            String reqTagValue = sheet1.getCell(0,Row).getContents()
            reqholder.setNodeValue("//*:"+reqTagName, reqTagValue)
            reqholder.updateProperty()                              
        }

    //test the request
    testRunner.runTestStepByName(reqOperationName)


    }

}
catch (Exception e) {log.info(e)}
finally{
    copy.write()
    copy.close()
    workbook.close()
}
log.info("Testing Over")
```

Also its better you move the test data input and test output results to different excel sheets. Your code right now uses single sheet for test data input and also to save to test results which is causing the problem.

Let me know if it worked. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the issue @sameer, after implementing the code which you had mentioned, it is removing all the datas from my sheet and yet no change in the soap request.... Instead i am getting an error as "Unexpected element: CDATA error at line 19" Below mentioned is the error log which i have encountered after adding the code.

Comment: the code is not replacing the value in soap request from excel sheet, also no execution is happening because of which i am not able to share contents of xml response. I am very much badly stuck in this please help me out.

Comment: Yeah I have replaced RequestAsXml to Request and tried ... i am not getting any errors in the error log... though in console i have an info as "INFO:java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath syntax error at char 11 on line 2 in {\ncount(//*:)}:
    expected "<name>", found ")"

Comment: The flow is not working after it enters def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context). When the flow reaches here i get an info as mentioned above.

Comment: If i add log.info reqTagName and try, it is removing all my data present in the excel sheet and giving property exception error.... I have added error log in the edit.

Comment: You need add : log.info reqTagName step immediately after this step : String reqTagName = sheet1.getCell(Col,0).getContents()

Comment: I have added where you have mentioned... It is now not removing the data from the excel sheet.... But the request is not passed in the soap request when i fire the groovy script... This is the info which i am getting in the log output:
"Tue Dec 05 10:59:28 IST 2017:INFO:java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath syntax error at char 11 on line 2 in {\ncount(//*:)}:
    expected "<name>", found ")"

Comment: Basically that means that variable is null.

Comment: So this means you couldn't get the data from excel sheet and the value is empty. Check your excel sheet if it has the correct data and also check excel sheet code

Comment: No, the values are present in the excel sheet are correct and also the excel sheet code. It is also reading the excel sheet but it's not putting the values from the excel sheet into the soap request... and also the test case is not executed when i fire the groovy script....

Comment: I have tried to debug and got to know that it's not proceeding further from "def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)"... from there it is throwing me "Tue Dec 05 12:18:28 IST 2017:INFO:java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath syntax error at char 11 on line 2 in {\ncount(//*:)}:
    expected "<name>", found ")""
After that i am getting message as "testing over"

Comment: Sagar, could you please attach a screenshot of your excel sheet to the question. I will try to use the same code and see what can be the problem

Comment: With the new fix i am getting "Tue Dec 05 14:21:49 IST 2017:INFO:java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath syntax error at char 11 on line 2 in {\ncount(//*:)}:
    expected "<name>", found ")"". Also, it's not executing the soap request when i fire the groovy script.
If i put testRunner.runTestStepByName(reqOperationName) after 
" String reqTagName = sheet1.getCell(Col,0).getContents()" then it executes the request but doesn't pick the value from excel sheet.

Comment: @SagarNaik, you need to separate code for test data input and output to two separate sheets. thats where the problem is right now. You are trying to do both from the same sheet of single workbook. i will share the new code. hold on

Comment: Yeah, I have tried with the changes which you had suggested but still it's not placing the values in the soap request from the excel sheet. 
I am getting 

Wed Dec 06 15:04:00 IST 2017:INFO:groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: jxl.write.Label(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, [Ljava.lang.String;)
in output log

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but is there any reason you cannot use a CSV file for what you are trying to achieve?

I only ask as when I have used Excel for data driven tests in the past, I have often found that extra characters/spaces can be added in.

Comment: Using .csv instead of .xls is throwing me some error which I am not even aware of... By using .xls atleast it is reading the data which I am trying to pass into.